# Bootstrap 3 breakpoint override not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, media-queries

I need to change the `@screen-lg-min` size to 1700px instead of 1200px (default).

I changed the the media query `@screen-lg-min` size in the variables.less file and compiled all files again using a gulp task. The css is generated correct, all the "lg" classes uses `min-width: 1700px;` but when I decrease the browser window to less than 1700px, nothing happens, and when is less than 1200px works like default.

I don't know why this behavior.

Hope someone can help me.

(Oh, I don't want to use the http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to change this value:

```
@container-large-desktop:      (1140px + @grid-gutter-width);
```

Comment: I'm using container-fluid class, so this don't work because I don't have a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

I'm using a bootstrap theme, so the bootstrap media query that I was trying to change was overridden by the theme. I changed the theme and works!